# How to identify columns that are sums of other columns in a dataset

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I would like to write a function (preferably in R, but other languages are welcome), which would identify relationships between columns (limited to additions/substractions) in a dataset. A practical application of this would be to run it on large multi-column financial datasets, where some of the columns are subtotals of other columns - and identify such subtotals.

Ideally, I would like to allow for small discrepancies - e.g. to allow for rounding issues leading to columns not adding up exactly 100%.

I found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088770/how-to-write-linearly-dependent-column-in-a-matrix-in-terms-of-linearly-independ) which includes a solution involving matrices and ranks, but I am not sure if there is any way to incorporate the ability to handle the noise in data arising from the rounding issues.

As an example:

```
d = data.frame(a=c(10.12, 20.02, 30.08, 20.19), b=c(12.12, 20.45, 20.52, 16.72), c=c(11, 123.25, 20.67, 20.78))
d$d = d$a + d$b
d$e = d$d + d$c
> d
      a     b      c     d      e
1 10.12 12.12  11.00 22.24  33.24
2 20.02 20.45 123.25 40.47 163.72
3 30.08 20.52  20.67 50.60  71.27
4 20.19 16.72  20.78 36.91  57.69

magic_function(d)
[1] "d$d = d$a + d$b"
[2] "d$e = d$d + d$c" # or "d$e = d$a + d$b + d$c" (first option preferred)
```

The solution in the linked question works well until I introduce noise into equation. e.g. `d$d[[4]] = d$d[[4]] + 0.01` - then it no longer works at all. My question thus is:

1. Are there any other methods to identifying relationships between
   columns (especially if they are restricted to simple
   addition/subtraction)
2. Are any of the methods able to address the
       imperfect data quality issue or do I need to build some additional
       functionality for it (e.g. round the data before running it through the rank identification algorithm).

Comment: A partial answer is to use `lm`. This should at least return the variables that are linear combinations of others as NA `summary(lm(rnorm(4) ~ ., data=d))` for example.

Comment: @lmo correct me if I am wrong, but lm requires knowing the dependent/independent variable(s) - in this case, I do not know what is dependent and what is independent..

Comment: That is true in theory and perhaps I am abusing the function, but notice that I added a random sample from the standard normal distribution as the dependent variable. Now, covariates (the "independent" variables) are evaluated as to their collinearity. If too close, then `lm` returns an NA. I believe (based on an earlier SO post) that covariates are selected in order of greater "independence,"  so those that are most collinear are left out in the regression results.

Comment: If you add a column of 1s as your first column the linked solution will be able to detect when you do something like d$d[[4]] <- d$d[[4]] + 0.01. The "small errors" thing due to rounding might cause an issue but why don't you try that first.  Basically if you add a column of 1s it allows for there to be a constant shift in the sum like you would do by adding 0.01 to the result.

Comment: Also you might want to include an example in your question where my linked solution doesn't worked.  If I used `linfinder(as.matrix(d))` on the input you supply I get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea which will work if you only need to check if any column is a result of the sum of any TWO others. It also allows you to add noise. We basically first create a data frame by adding all combinations of original data set. We then subtract each column of data set with created data frame. If all the values are 0 it means they match. By using `colSums(i < 0.01) == nrow(i))`, we are able to add the required noise.

```
d2 <- setNames(data.frame(combn(1:ncol(d), 2, function(i) rowSums(d[i]))), 
                combn(names(d), 2, function(j)paste(j, collapse = ' + ')))

l1 <- lapply(d, function(i) sapply(d2, function(j) Map(function(x, y)abs(x - y), i, j)))

lapply(l1, function(i) names(which(colSums(i < 0.01) == nrow(i))))

#$a
#character(0)

#$b
#character(0)

#$c
#character(0)

#$d
#[1] "a + b"

#$e
#[1] "c + d"
```

Or make it a function with `noise` as input argument,

```
f1 <- function(df, noise){
  d2 <- setNames(data.frame(combn(1:ncol(df), 2, function(i) rowSums(df[i]))), 
                 combn(names(df), 2, function(j)paste(j, collapse = ' + ')))
  l1 <- lapply(df, function(i) sapply(d2, function(j) 
                       Map(function(x, y)abs(x - y), i, j)))
  Filter(length, lapply(l1, function(i) 
                names(which(colSums(i < noise) == nrow(i)))))
}

f1(d, 0.01)
#$d
#[1] "a + b"

#$e
#[1] "c + d"
```

If we want to make it more flexible, then we can add another argument to take the combination number (of columns), i.e.

```
f1 <- function(df, n, noise){
  d2 <- setNames(data.frame(combn(1:ncol(df), n, function(i) rowSums(df[i]))), 
                 combn(names(df), n, function(j)paste(j, collapse = ' + ')))
  l1 <- lapply(df, function(i) sapply(d2, function(j) 
                       Map(function(x, y)abs(x - y), i, j)))
  Filter(length, lapply(l1, function(i) 
                names(which(colSums(i < noise) == nrow(i)))))
}

sapply(2:3, function(i) f1(d, i, 0.01))
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$d
#[1] "a + b"

#[[1]]$e
#[1] "c + d"

#[[2]]
#[[2]]$e
#[1] "a + b + c"
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the practical cases will almost always involve more than 2 columns. I'd assume this approach is not very scalable to support at least, say, 10-20 columns?

Comment: If you mean that 1 column might be the product of the sum of 10 or 20 others then no, this won't work. You will have to change the `combn` parameter from 2 to any number of columns you would want

Comment: @Aurimas I edited the function to make it more flexible though I suspect it would not perform very well in terms of efficiency

Comment: Thanks - will try to play around with it and some real examples to see how it works

Answer (score 0):

If you allow the sums to only be for *consecutive* columns, and for previous values only, the computational effort for this is probably tractable for 10-20 columns. This procedure checks to see if the column is equal to the sum of previous consecutive columns, with some allowance for error:

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(10.12, 20.02, 30.08, 20.19),
                b=c(12.12, 20.45, 20.52, 16.72),
                c=c(11, 123.25, 20.67, 20.78));
d$d <- round(d$a + d$b + runif(4,0,0.04),2);
d$e <- round(d$d + d$c + runif(4,0,0.04),2);

## Assumptions:
## * sum columns relate to previous values only
## * sum columns relate to consecutive columns

sumColumns <- NULL;
allowedError <- 0.05;
for(col in 3:ncol(d)){
    for(subStart in 1:(col-2)){
        for(subEnd in (subStart+1):(col-1)){
            if(all(abs(d[,col] - rowSums(d[,subStart:subEnd, drop=FALSE])) <
                   allowedError)){
                cat(sprintf("Column %d is a sum of columns %d-%d\n",
                            col, subStart, subEnd));
                sumColumns[col] <- TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Column 4 is a sum of columns 1-2
Column 5 is a sum of columns 3-4
```

This could be modified to allow for consecutive columns together with any number of sum columns while maintaining tractability (assuming the number of sum columns were kept low). That modification is not completely trivial, and is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks - in real datasets, the "consecutiveness" limitation will mean that "second order" subtotals would not be identified (i.e. where a+b=c, d+e=f, and g=c+f), but I see where this may still be useful!

Comment: That's where the inclusion of sum columns helps. If you allow non-consecutive sum columns together with consecutive non-sum columns, any second order totals will also be included.